# Jackson forwarding attribute instead of outer object

Tags: java, jackson

I have an object that is used as a return type in a REST web service (jax-rs). The object contains a field which is an array of another type. Example:

```
  @Name("PARAMETER_DEFINITION_TABTYPE")
  @TableOfDefinition
  @XmlType(
      name = "parameter_DEFINITION_TABTYPE"
  )
  class PARAMETER_DEFINITION_TABTYPE {

    @XmlElement(
        name = "parameter_definition_rectype",
        nillable = true
    )
    public PARAMETER_DEFINITION_RECTYPE[] ELEMENTS;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return ELEMENTS == null ? null : java.util.Arrays.toString(ELEMENTS);
    }
  }
```

I use all the existing annotations to create my SOAP web services and don't want to touch the class or the existing annotations. The REST service I create uses the same class and generates the following json:

```
{"parameter_definition_rectype": [
   {
       "name": "abc"
   },
   {
       "name": "abss"
   }
]}
```

I would like to get the following output (basically ignore the outer element and use only the "ELEMENTS" field):

```
[
   {
       "name": "abc"
   },
   {
       "name": "abss"
   }
]
```

I also want to ignore the outer object when the PARAMETER_DEFINITION_TABTYPE  is nested in another Object.
Is there a way I can achieve this by using annotations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a custom serializer and deserializer for `PARAMETER_DEFINITION_TABTYPE` class which will change the way it's processed by `ObjectMapper`.

This is explained in the wiki [`Jackson How-To: Custom Serializers`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers), if you can't add new annotations to `PARAMETER_DEFINITION_TABTYPE` class you should use [a custom module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers#with-jackson-17-and-above).

It's more or less the below code. The problem here is that you have to provide a lot of custom code to get desired behavior. It would be cleaner to have a separate class to represent the JSON object because it's different than XML object:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("WrapperModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));
    module.addSerializer(Wrapper.class, new WrapperSerializer(Wrapper.class));
    module.addDeserializer(Wrapper.class, new WrapperDeserializer(Wrapper.class));

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(module);

    Wrapper in = new Wrapper();
    in.elements = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};

    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(in);
    System.out.println(json);

    Wrapper out = mapper.readValue(json, Wrapper.class);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(out.elements));
}


public static class Wrapper {

    public String[] elements;

}

public static class WrapperSerializer extends StdSerializer<Wrapper> {

    public WrapperSerializer(Class<Wrapper> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Wrapper w, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        provider.defaultSerializeValue(w.elements, gen);
    }

}

public static class WrapperDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Wrapper> {

    public WrapperDeserializer(Class<Wrapper> c) {
        super(c);
    }

    @Override
    public Wrapper deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException {
        Wrapper w = new Wrapper();
        w.elements = ctx.readValue(p, String[].class);
        return w;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed and quick answer. The solution using a serializer works for me (the web service implementation is generated anyways, so I can also generate the serializers).